# Firebase Push Notifications does not receive

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm trying firebase push notification. I did everything it said in the tutorial, but it isn't working.

FirebaseMessagingService:

```
  package com.example.firebasenf.firebasenf;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;/

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
}
```

FirebaseInstanceIdService:

```
package com.example.firebasenf.firebasenf;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
}
```

Manifest:

```
            <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: Make a notification method atleast to send notification..its not a magic that will happen

Comment: Is this your full code??

Comment: yes, but i did the same what i saw here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZtDZyW4Zvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add some methods to your code :

FirebaseMessagingService:

```
    package com.example.firebasenf.firebasenf;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Application Title");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

FirebaseInstanceIdService :

```
package com.example.firebasenf.firebasenf;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String REG_TOKEN = "REG_TOKEN";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh(){
        String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(REG_TOKEN,recent_token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to override `onMessageReceived` in `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class to do some actions when notification is pushed.

[doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

> By overriding the method FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived,
>   you can perform actions based on the received RemoteMessage object and
>   get the message data

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
{

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + "Notification Received");


    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

    //You may want show notification
}
```

keep in mind `onMessageReceived` will only triggered if the app in foreground

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification
>   messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the
>   app launcher by default.